# Python Re: Substitute unkown number of expressions within a fixed expression

Tags: python, regex

I would like to use the python re module to substitute an unknown number of expressions which always fall between two expressions so that any expressions which starts with `</w:t>` and ends with `<w:t>` between `{{` and `}}` are substituted. So far I have:

```
    import re
    a = re.compile(r'</w:t>.*?<w:t>')
    a.sub('', 'input_string')
```

I think the pattern may be too greedy, but the main issue is that I would like to substitute zero or more instances of any expression that matches this pattern only if it falls between `{{` and `}}`. Please can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Comment: `input_string = re.sub(r'(?s){{.*?}}', lambda x: re.sub(r'(?s)</w:t>.*?<w:t>', '', x.group()), input_string)`

Comment: By "starts with </w:t> and ends with <w:t> between {{ and }} are substituted" do you mean `<w:t>{{something here}}</w:t>` or `{{<w:t>something here</w:t>}}` and you want to replace `something here` with something else? From the description it seems you mean the latter, is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  may match all substrings between `{{` and `}}` and remove all occurrences of the second pattern only inside the matches:

```
input_string = re.sub(r'(?s){{.*?}}', lambda x: re.sub(r'(?s)</w:t>.*?<w:t>', '', x.group()), input_string)
```

The `(?s){{.*?}}` regex matches `{{`, any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the leftmost `}}` including them, and then all substrings between `</w:t>` and `<w:t>` are removed only inside the matches with the `lambda x: re.sub(r'(?s)</w:t>.*?<w:t>', '', x.group())` replacement.